# Ubuntu in Acer will become idle while using

Tags: 13.04, acer

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 in my Acer Aspire V5 121.  Speed is low compared to Windows. It will become idle while using. Nothing will work at that time. And we have to switch off and switch on using power button.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! your question is a little bit vague, please  reformulate to [clearly express what you expect](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). And give more information about your hardware, example specify what is your graphic card, and which driver are your using, it could help others to explain you how to improve your performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

install your aspire's display graphic drivers